# LiveData Consumer in BaseFragment not receiving updates from BaseViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata

I have a BaseFragment.kt that looks like this

```
open class BaseFragment: Fragment() {

private lateinit var viewModel: BaseViewModel

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(BaseViewModel::class.java)
    observeNavigationCommands()
}

/**
 * Method that observes Navigation commands triggered by BaseViewHolder
 * This allows us to navigate from a viewHolder using the MVVM pattern
 */
private fun observeNavigationCommands() {
    viewModel.navigationCommands.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, EventObserver {
        Timber.e("received nav command $it")
        when(it) {
            is NavigationCommand.To -> findNavController().navigate(it.destinationId)
            is NavigationCommand.Back -> findNavController().popBackStack()
            is NavigationCommand.BackTo -> TODO()
            NavigationCommand.ToRoot -> TODO()
        }
    })
}
```

}

...and a BaseViewModel.kt that looks like this

```
open class BaseViewModel: ViewModel() {

val navigationCommands = MutableLiveData<Event<NavigationCommand>>()

/**
 * Navigate to a specific fragment using Id
 */
fun navigate(id: Int) {
    Timber.e("trigger navigation event $id")
    // navigationCommands.postValue(NavigationCommand.To(id))
    navigationCommands.value = Event(NavigationCommand.To(id))
}

/**
 * Pop backStack
 */
fun goBack() {
    navigationCommands.value = Event(NavigationCommand.Back)
}
```

}

the `NavigationCommand` class looks like

```
sealed class NavigationCommand {

data class To(val destinationId: Int) : NavigationCommand()
data class BackTo(val destinationId: Int): NavigationCommand()

object Back: NavigationCommand()
object ToRoot: NavigationCommand()
```

}

Now in my other viewModels that extend `BaseViewModel` I want to be able to call
`navigate(R.id.action_fragmentA_to_fragmentB)` but the issue is that the consumer in `observeNavigationCommands()` never receives the NavigationCommands

.....

But if I copy the content of `observeNavigationCommands()` and place it in my current fragment (the one that extends `BaseFragment`) the consumer receives the updates

what am I missing? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do I understand correctly that for your fragment that extends `BaseFragment`, you want to attach a viewModel that extends `BaseViewModel`, but that doesn't work for you with the liveData?

If so, check out this simple working project that I created to mirror you case:

https://github.com/phamtdat/OpenViewModelDemo

The point is to make the `viewModel` overridedable and override it in your fragment that extends `BaseFragment`.

Comment: thanks for your solution, but what i want is to be able to call the navigate methods from the ViewModel, not the fragment...

I modified your code to that effect and run into the same problem I currently have

Please modify your empty MyViewModel class to have a wrapper method, eg:
`fun mNav() { naviagte(123456) }`

and test by calling `mNav()` instead of `navigate(123456)` from your fragment, im sure you;d  see what im talking about

Comment: Hm, can't reproduce what you are describing. I see the logs that the events were triggered. Maybe there is an issue with the `Event` class that I am not using, what's the build.gradle dependency for it? I did not use it as I didn't know the dependency. If you have the modified code that reproduces the issue, make a pull request to the repository and I will have a look. Check it anyway as I made update with the wrapped functions.

Comment: By the way, why use wrapper function and not make `navigate` open fun and override it in the `MyViewModel`? there you do your own logic and then call `super.navigate(...)`, and then in the fragment you won't need to do any class cast

Comment: Thanks... your solution works but I have created a pull request to the repo with some changes that attempt to describe my scenario... please take a look...

Comment: Ok, I finally understood your issue. Check out the repository's new update to see if that answers your question. Start with MySampleFragment

Comment: I tried to upvote but my reputation is low, below 15 :( unfortunately. Apparently, it is recorded but does not change the publicly displayed post score.